# how would I identify when and who enter through a doorway, assuming they can have part of the technology on their person

Tags: sensors, electrical, wireless-communication

I am working on setting up a system that senses when an object goes though a door. I've seen things using lasers or induction. I have a set of objects smaller than 1 square inch. I just want to know which object goes through the "door". Think of the object as empty and the sensors can go anywhere or everywhere around the door.

The time doesn't need to be too accurate, within a second.

I just haven't decided on a bunch of stuff, I just know that the item should be able to held on your person and the "door" could be a door or just an entranceway to another room ( you know, like a big doorway but without the door). I want to track when someone goes through a "doorway", I don't know how to describe that. The height will be door height and the width could be larger, up to 10 ft I guess. The speed would be walking speed usually. The object would be on the person without being annoying to carry. In my head it's just an object, not sure what else. I would like it to be able to be in a pocket though.

basically I would like to know how many people enter a room and who they are.

Comment: laser, photoelectric sensor but depends on ambient lighting, or mass detection.

Comment: what if the object was in the person's pocket?

Comment: Internally fit one of those rfid chips as used on pets…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Radio frequency ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) [chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_module) are an easy way to achieve what you want.

Some stores place them on their high valued merchandise items to prevent theft. RF reading devices are located at the entrances and when a RF ID chip, that hasn't been canceled, passes near such a device and alarm is activated.

Some airlines use them to track luggage for the frequent flyer customers.

Such devices can be placed in lanyard that people were around their necks and as they pass through a doorway which has a reader next to it the RF ID chip is noted and a computerized database is updated.

Depending on the application, various sized FR ID devices can be obtained.

Comment: I've seen that commented elsewhere, do you think it could be directional enough to use in smaller buildings like a house, to know what room everyone is in? would this just be an issue of antenna shape?

Comment: @selacey You seem to be changing your question as we go. You originally asked about sensing someone passing **through a doorway** and RFID might work for that. Now you want to make it "directional" to "know what room everyone is in". That is a much different problem. You would need to use an RFID reader at **every doorway** and somehow keep track of when each person enters and leaves each room. That is a non-trivial task, particularly if people can pass by the doorway without going through it.

Comment: I agree with @ElliotAlderson regarding having RFID readers at each doorway if you want directional information. The counter the problem of someone passing a doorway & activating the RFID reader without going through the doorway you may need to install limited range readers on both sides of each doorway to register when someone leaves on room & enters the other room.